# Why does spring security ask for authentication even after including endpoint in permitAll()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Boot 3.2.2 with spring security. I have 3 endpoints for which I  permitAll(). The strange thing is that only for the /upload endpoint permit all does not work. It still asks for authentication and even after authentication it throws 403. Even if I move the /upload endpoint to the requestMatchers() for ADMIN or USER it still throws 403, while the other endpoints work.

The only difference between these endpoints is that /upload is a POST request and it takes in a MultipartFile, while the others are simple GET requests.

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
 @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/test/user").hasRole(UserRole.USER.name())
                        .requestMatchers("/test/admin").hasRole(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                        .requestMatchers("/test/no-role", "/upload", "/api/ai/generate").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
```

Update:

Changed logging level to debug. Here are the logs:

```
2024-02-13T12:50:34.003+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /upload
2024-02-13T12:50:34.005+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/upload
2024-02-13T12:50:34.007+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
2024-02-13T12:50:34.009+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-02-13T12:50:34.009+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=admin, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=7579E5587784A8B4847F2571BCD188A2], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]]]
2024-02-13T12:50:34.009+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error
2024-02-13T12:50:34.009+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2024-02-13T12:50:34.010+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2024-02-13T12:50:34.010+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2024-02-13T12:50:34.012+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2024-02-13T12:50:34.013+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Tue Feb 13 12:50:34 EET 2024, status=403, error=Forbidden, path=/upload}]
2024-02-13T12:50:34.022+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2024-02-13T12:50:34.022+02:00 DEBUG 16611 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403
```

Comment: Check if there is not set any part of path before  `/upload`

Comment: @Andrei Lisa checked. that is not the issue.

Comment: pleaes enable spring `DEBUG` logs and edit your question to include the full logs

Comment: Show your request with headers. Show your Spring Security `DEBUG` logs. Most likely it is a CSRF problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your configuration the problem that you get is related to `csrf` and in current one configuration to permit the `POST` requests,  you have to disable it. Because it is enabled by default in spring security.

Something like it you have to add to configuration:

```
http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
```

More details you could find into relevant section in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html)

Comment: You are right it was a csrf issue. Thanks! 
To bad the question was closed. I feel that sometimes it is really hard to ask a question on SO.